# How can I run CodeMirror "runMode" in a Web Worker without having document is not defined?

Tags: typescript, web-worker, codemirror

I have a (typescript) compiler running in a Web Worker and I need it to parse the source for literal values in the script. I have been using CodeMirror.runMode for this and it works fine, but loading CodeMirror inside the Web Worker generates errors.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

How can I load CodeMirror to parse code in a Web Worker ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution:

There is a 'runmode-standalone' script in CodeMirror that does just what I need. It works but I had to do some hot fixes to some files.

Load the standalone runmode script:

```
// @ts-ignore
import CM = require('codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode-standalone')
// JS mode
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript'
```

Hot fix (using patch-package to save the changes in my project):

```
// Start of node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js

// This avoids loading CodeMirror if it is already loaded through standalone
(function (global, factory) {
  if (self.CodeMirror) {
    factory = function() { return self.CodeMirror }
  }
```

```
// Start of node_modules/codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode-standalone.js

self.CodeMirror = {} // instead of window.CodeMirror
```

Note that this solution works in Web Worker and with the full CodeMirror in the browser  yeah !